# Is there a good way to do an overlapping copy in ndarray in rust?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust, copy, borrowing, nalgebra

Here's what I tried

```
use ndarray::{arr2, s};
let mut a = arr2(&[[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6]]);
let b = arr2(&[[2, 3, 3],
               [5, 6, 6]]);

a.slice_mut(s![.., ..2]).assign(&a.slice_mut(s![.., 1..]));
```

which obviously fails because of the borrowing rules ([playround link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d62ba7d22f3e304382c5e2148be7ee36)):

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `a` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:13:38
   |
13 |     a.slice_mut(s![.., ..2]).assign(&a.slice_mut(s![.., 1..]));
   |     -                        ------  ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |     |                        |
   |     |                        first borrow later used by call
   |     first mutable borrow occurs here
```

Here `a` is what I have and `b` is what I'm trying to get.

In numpy it is as easy as `a[:, :2] = a[:, 1:]`.

PS Maybe there's a simple solution in `nalgebra` crate?

Comment: Why don't you write a for loop?

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios just one for loop wont solve all the aliasing problems that might arise (eg left-to-right vs right-to-left copying). Also I'd expect the library do that for me, or at least help me with that. Otherwise I'd resort to plain C.

Answer (score 0):

In master branch of ndarray there's a special macro for that, more convenient than `split_at_mut()` in that it supports arbitrary slices - but it panics when the slices overlap:

```rust
use ndarray::multislice;
use ndarray::prelude::*;
let mut arr: Array1<_> = (0..4).collect();
let (mut a, mut b) = multislice!(arr, mut [..;2], mut [1..;2]);
a.assign(&b);
```

gives `[1,1,3,3]`

They even solve a Diophantine equation to check it. It happens at runtime as opposed to compile-time `split_at_mut`.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, got it

```
use ndarray::{arr2, s,Array};

let mut a = arr2(&[[1, 2, 3],
                   [4, 5, 6]]);
unsafe{
    let b = a.as_mut_ptr();
    let c = Vec::<i32>::from_raw_parts(b, 6, 6);
    let mut d = Array::from_shape_vec((2, 3), c).unwrap();
    a.slice_mut(s![.., ..2]).assign(&d.slice_mut(s![.., 1..]));
    std::mem::forget(d);
}
println!("{:?}",a);
```

Comment: Note that there is no guaranty that this code will work: the order in which `assign` moves elements is not defined, so a future version of Rust or `ndarray` could break your code.

Comment: It also wouldn't work if you wanted to move data to the right instead of moving them to the left…

Comment: This program leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jmb yes, it needs some logic similar to memmove implementation: reverse the slice if the moving to the left